# Skype4Py: Change the role of a group chat member

Tags: python, skype4py

I have a skypebot with commands. One of the commands I'm trying to implement is "promote_to_master":

```
# chat is Skype4Py.chat.Chat object, user_string is str
def promote_to_master(self, chat, user_string):
    if self.is_creator_or_master(chat):
        for member in chat.Members:
            if member.Handle == user_string:
                logging.info("Member promoted")
                member.Role = Skype4Py.chatMemberRoleMaster

    return "Member promoted"
```

The bot is a MASTER, the target a USER. No errors are thrown, but the member's role is not changed in the chat. I do see the log entry. `print type(member)` shows `<class 'Skype4Py.user.User'>`, which it seems can't have a Role changed, but I'm not sure.

In the group chat, a commander uses: `!promote user`
After running, using `/whois user` gives:

```
member: user
role: USER
subscribed: YES
banned: NO
online locations: [scrubbed]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took 2 extra steps to get to where I wanted to be:

1. I was using `chat.Members` when I needed `chat.MemberObjects`
2. The bot had to be the `CREATOR` for my little trio of testing accounts. It may have something to do with who adds which user. Previously, my bot was a `MASTER` and user1 was `CREATOR`. I don't know how a user's AddedBy property affects a user, but it does something. Now that my bot is `CREATOR`, I can affect other users' roles.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Skype bot as well. 
You can do something like this:

```
                        elif msg.startswith('!listener '):
                    debug.action('!listener command executed.')
                    string = msg.replace('!listener ', '', 1)
                    send('/setrole '+string+' listener')
```

Then do

```
                        elif msg.startswith('!helper '):
                    debug.action('!helper command executed.')
                    string = msg.replace('!helper ', '', 1)
                    send('/setrole '+string+' helper')
```

and so on, so that way you can just type a command in chat on Skype to demote/promote people via the bot.

Good luck :)